# How to get an Enum value from a Multimap

Tags: java, json, enums, guava, multimap

Here is my `enum`:

```java
public enum StaffRanks {

    HELPER("helpers"),
    MODERATOR("moderators"),
    ADMINISTRATOR("administrators"),
    DEVELOPER("developers"),
    OWNER("owners");

    private String name;

    StaffRanks(String name) {
        this.setName(name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

This is how I create my `Multimap`:

```java
public static Multimap<String, StaffRanks> staffMembers;

public static void fetchPlayerRanks() {
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

    try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(".\\Data\\staff_list.json"));
        JsonObject staffList = (JsonObject) obj;

        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {
        }.getType();

        staffMembers = ArrayListMultimap.create();

        for (StaffRanks rank : StaffRanks.values()) {
            staffMembers.put(new Gson().fromJson(staffList.get(rank.getName()), listType), rank);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is how I want to use it:

```java
int index = 39550;

for (String player : allStaffNames) {

    onlineStatus = "@red@Offline";

    if (onlineStaff.contains(PlayerHandler.getPlayer(player))) {
        onlineStatus = "@gre@Online";
    }

    if (staffMembers.containsKey(player)) {
        playerClient.getPA().sendFrame126("[" + staffMembers.get(player).getName() + "]@cya@" + Misc.formatPlayerName(player) + ": ", index);
    }

    playerClient.getPA().sendFrame126(onlineStatus, index - 1);

    index += 2;
}
```

Now, the question is: how I can get the name from the enum inside the `Multimap`?

Here is what I tried. But, it didn't work.

```java
staffMembers.get(player).getName()
```

Here is what the `Staff_list.json` file looks like:

```json
{
    "owners":['chuck'],
    "developers":['tyrant','stan'],
    "serverManagers":['logical'],
    "staffManagers":['bench press', 'bench press2'],
    "communityManagers":['cleave'],
    "administrators":['zeven', 'reavers', 'redaeran', 'stuart'],
    "moderators":['searwen', 'potentials', 'maud', 'lickylicky'],
    "helpers":['megafun12', 'rhysj', 'vaping', 'punch']
}
```

Comment: How does the `staff_list.json` entries look like? And how does the `player` string literal looks like? That should be the trick...

Comment: @tmarwen added the json file, thanks already :)

Comment: Could you additionnaly state what is the part of your example that does not work? And what is the error that gets thrown and at which part? I hardly coulf see that it even compile.

Answer (score 0):

Because `staffMembers` is defined as `Multimap<String, StaffRanks>`, it means that you should read this as `Map<String, Collection<StaffRanks>>` with shiny Guava interface for such case (i.e. mapping key to a *collection* of values). So in your case what you're actually trying to do is:

```
Collection<StaffRanks> staffRanksForPlayer = staffMembers.get(player);
staffRanksForPlayer.getName(); // BOOM!
```

If you read / attached an error message, it would be much easier. Anyway, you have two options here:

1. You're using wrong collection type because you want `Map<String, StaffRank>` if one player can have only one rank - if so, change collection to `Map` and you're good.
2. You have to find a matching rank somehow or use all of them in your code. For example, the latter could be achieved with Java 8:

   ```
   List<String> staffRanksNamesForPlayer = staffMembers.get(player).stream()
       .map(StaffRanks::getName)
       .collect(Collectors.toList());

   // use list's `toString()` in your code to print its contents
   playerClient.getPA().sendFrame126("[" + staffRanksNamesForPlayer.toString()
        + "]@cya@" + Misc.formatPlayerName(player) + ": ", index);
   ```

One more thing: generally you want to specify which specific `Multimap` interface you're using: [`ListMultimap`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html) or [`SetMultimap`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/SetMultimap.html).